# How to overwrite default git source in autoproj?

Tags: rock

I want to overwrite the git source of a package in autoproj. That package is by 
default on gitorious and I forked it on spacegit to apply specific patches.
According to the autoproj documentation (http://rock-robotics.org/stable/documentation/autoproj/customization.html), I set the new repo in the overrides.yml by:

```
  - control/orogen/<package>:
    url: git://spacegit.dfki.uni-bremen.de/virgo/orogen-<package>.git
```

But if I inspect the remotes of the newly checked out package, only the 
fetch url is adapted to spacegit whereas the push url still points to 
the default gitorious repo:

```
$ git remote -v
autobuild   git://spacegit.dfki.uni-bremen.de/<project>/orogen-<package>.git (fetch)
autobuild   git@gitorious.org:/rock-control/orogen-<package>.git (push)
```

How can I overwrite both the fetch and the push source of a package in the 
overrides.yml?

Comment: This is not a robotics-related question. Please try a software related stackexchange such as stackoverflow or programming.stackexchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about managing a GIT repository

Comment: autoproj being the build system of a robotics framework (http://rock-robotics.org), and since the question is tagged properly, it is IMO relevant here.

Comment: This is not a question about robotics, it is a question about a build system which happens to contain code related to robotics. While I'm happy for this to remain here since it already has an accepted answer, `git` questions are more likely to be answered more comprehensively on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the part that autobuild can separate between push and pull urls.

See documentation at
http://rock-robotics.org/next/api/autobuild/Autobuild/Git.html

The Gitorious statement automatically set the push_to url, see here:
http://rock-robotics.org/next/api/autoproj/Autoproj.html#method-c-gitorious_server_configuration

everything you have to do is add:

```
- control/orogen/<package>:
  url: git://spacegit.dfki.uni-bremen.de/virgo/orogen-<package>.git
  push_to: git@spacegit.dfki.uni-bremen.de:virgo/orogen-<package>.git
```